# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This Dispatcher has been shut down

Tags: mongodb, grails, integration-testing, spock

I have implemented Spock Integration test TestControllerIntegrationSpec on Grails, Groovy,GROM and Mongodb environment and the Test case has been passed when only one Interation test class available in my development environment.But fails when development environment has more than one Integration test

Ran the test case "gradle clean integrationTest"

```
This Dispatcher has been shut down.; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This Dispatcher has been shut down.
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: This Dispatcher has been shut down.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This Dispatcher has been shut down.
    at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:127)
    at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:55)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at com.TestControllerIntegrationSpec.setup(TestControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This Dispatcher has been shut down.
    at reactor.core.support.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:61)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:111)
    at reactor.bus.EventBus.notify(EventBus.java:368)
    at grails.events.Events$Trait$Helper.notify(Events.groovy:111)
    at org.grails.events.spring.SpringEventTranslator.onApplicationEvent(SpringEventTranslator.groovy:66)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.ConfigurableApplicationContextEventPublisher.publishEvent(ConfigurableApplicationContextEventPublisher.groovy:30)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.publishSessionCreationEvent(AbstractDatastore.java:125)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.connect(AbstractDatastore.java:118)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.connect(AbstractDatastore.java:113)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.transactions.DatastoreTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(DatastoreTransactionManager.java:101)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:337)
    at org.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.registerTransactionManager(MultiTransactionStatus.java:68)
    at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:106)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Could you find root cause of this?